# Input box that expands to display content to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

After a while thinking about this, I think I could use more brain power.

Imagine the following UI (courtesy of StackOverflow):
[image]
Note that the red lines are 'guides'. Imagine that they are `<div/>` boundaries.

What I want is that when a lot of text is added to the input box, enough to overflow, the input box should 'pop out' and overlay/autosize to the left, like the image below:

[image]

This is somewhat similar to how Stackoverflow's works, except that it resizes according to content. Also, similarly to stackoverflow, it need to retract when the input box looses focus.

Usually, I'd come to SO prepared with some code, but this time, it's a bit difficult.

- What exactly should I use to 'fix' the input box to the right?
- How do I find the internal/content width of the input box?
  Note that I'm using a monospaced font, so this might be easier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found the answer....or uhm...created the solution.

It can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PaBus/3/).

In short, it is mainly a lot of events and a 'fake' input box with absolute positioning.